# How to set the TreeView node fore color in c#?

Tags: c#, treeview

In my project i have to set fore color for Treeview node as blue **which node have children nodes** that nodes only in blue color,remaining nodes are having default color,Here my doubt is in which event i write the code for setting the fore color for treeview nodes.

regards
Krishna

Comment: You could just create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in your Xaml to handle the colors for the child nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeView.Node has a ForeColor and a BackColor property, is that what you are looking for?
Something like this:

```
        TreeView tv = new TreeView();

        tv.Nodes.Add("node1", "Node 1");
        tv.Nodes.Add("node2", "Node 2");

        tv.Nodes["node1"].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        tv.Nodes["node2"].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

To check for child nodes of a particular node:

```
        node.ForeColor = node.Nodes.Count > 0
           ? System.Drawing.Color.Blue
           : System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Here my requirement is who has the child nodes those node become blue color with bold font,else default color and font for my treeview.